# -label:pinned works in Gmail but not in the Google Apps Script GmailApp.search() function?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-inbox

The following **Gmail / Inbox By Gmail** search returns everything in my inbox that is pinned.

`in:inbox label:pinned`

And this returns all unpinned inbox messages.

`in:inbox -label:pinned`

*side note: Even though messages are "pinned" in Inbox By Gmail, and not Gmail, the search still works as expected in both web apps.*

The following Google Apps Script logs only pinned emails.

```
function GetUnpinnedEmails() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox label:pinned');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      subject = message.getSubject();

      Logger.log(subject)
  }
}
```

However, the following Google Apps Script logs *all* inbox emails ***including pinned messages***.

```
function GetUnpinnedEmails() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search('in:inbox -label:pinned');

  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
      message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
      subject = message.getSubject();

      Logger.log(subject)
  }
}
```

`GmailApp.search('in:inbox NOT label:pinned')` also returns all inbox messages.

I think this is a bug but I thought I'd see if I'm missing something.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No longer an problem. Google fixed the issue.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64715312